# React Reusable State modifying method or component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have 2 dashboards in my application, one for Devices and other for Desktop. Both of them needs a method which can modify the state. And this method contains the conditional statements which decides the value to be updated in state. And for my scenario, this method can be absolutely be used by both Desktop and Device Dashboard to alter the required state. Now, to achieve this, what I understand is, I have to put this method in both stateful components, DesktopDashboard and DeviceDashboard and hence making my code redundant. I cannot identify the way I can pull this particular state modifying method out of these 2 components and use it from single place as a common method. Below is the code what I have:

**webDashboard Component**

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import JourneyList from './JourneyList';
import CONSTANTS from './Constants';
class webDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            journeyMessageList: [{ messageId: XYPZ, type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.HOW_MAY_I_HELP_YOU }, time: new Date()},
            { messageId: XYPZ, type: CONSTANTS.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS, time: new Date()} ]
        };

    }

    updateMyState = (source, typedText) => {
     this.setState({
            journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList, 
                    { messageId: XXXX, type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                ]
        });
        if(CONSTANTS.SOURCE_USER_INPUT.MDN === source) {

            this.setState({
                journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList.filter((ele) => ele.type !== CONSTANTS.MDN_USER_INPUT),
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ASK_SSS }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.SSS_USER_INPUT, data: { text: "INPUTBOX" }, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, time: new Date()}
                ]  
            });
        } else if(CONSTANTS.SOURCE_USER_INPUT.NRIC === source) {
            this.setState({
                journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList.filter((ele) => ele.type !== CONSTANTS.NRIC_USER_INPUT),
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ELIGIBLE_FOR_SERVICE }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.CONFIRM_CURRENT_DEVICE, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.CONFIRM_CURRENT_DEVICE, time: new Date()}
                ]
            });
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }else{
            .....
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment> <JourneyList messages={this.state.journeyMessageList} 
                    updateJourneyList={this.updateMyState} />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }

};

export default webDashboard;
```

**deviceDashboard Component**

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import DeviceChatWindow from './DeviceChatWindow';
import CONSTANTS from './Constants';
class deviceDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            journeyMessageList: [{ messageId: XYPZ, type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.HOW_MAY_I_HELP_YOU }, time: new Date()},
            { messageId: XYPZ, type: CONSTANTS.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS, time: new Date()} ]
        };

    }

    updateMyState = (source, typedText) => {
     this.setState({
            journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList, 
                    { messageId: XXXX, type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                ]
        });
        if(CONSTANTS.SOURCE_USER_INPUT.MDN === source) {

            this.setState({
                journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList.filter((ele) => ele.type !== CONSTANTS.MDN_USER_INPUT),
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ASK_SSS }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'dfsdf', type: CONSTANTS.SSS_USER_INPUT, data: { text: "INPUTBOX" }, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, time: new Date()}
                ]  
            });
        } else if(CONSTANTS.SOURCE_USER_INPUT.NRIC === source) {
            this.setState({
                journeyMessageList: [...this.state.journeyMessageList.filter((ele) => ele.type !== CONSTANTS.NRIC_USER_INPUT),
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.ME, data: { text: typedText }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.TEXT, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: { text: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.ELIGIBLE_FOR_SERVICE }, time: new Date()},
                    { messageId: 'ghfgh', type: CONSTANTS.CONFIRM_CURRENT_DEVICE, author: CONSTANTS.SYSTEM, data: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.CONFIRM_CURRENT_DEVICE, time: new Date()}
                ]
            });
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }elsee if(Many Such Conditions){
            .....
        }else{
            .....
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>  <div id="appBody" className="row app-body">
                    <div id="chatWindow" className="col-md-9 app-message-window">
                        <DeviceChatWindow
                            journeyMessageList={this.state.journeyMessageList}
                            updateJourneyList={this.updateMyState}
                        />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }

};

export default deviceDashboard;
```

Here, the method, **updateMyState**, is what I want to use it as a reusable one, to avoid redundancy, but I cannot figure out how I can have it at a common place such that it can change state whenever the calling/redering component calls for it.

Note: The constants.jsx contains simple key/value pair constant like:

```
const CONSTANTS = {
  TEXT:"Hi There",
ME:"me",
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`setState()` also accepts a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that gets passed the `state` and `props` as arguments and should return the new state. You could extract your updating logic into a static function like:

```
// in myModule.js

const updateState = (state, props) => {
    // calculate new state
    // const newState = ...

    return newState;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
import updateState from 'myModule';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    updateMyState = () => this.setState(updateState);

    render() {
        return (
            <JourneyList messages={this.state.journeyMessageList} 
                updateJourneyList={this.updateMyState} />
        );
    }
}
```

Of course you can also add arbitrary arguments to that function:

```
const updateState = (state, props, source, typedText) => {/* calculate new state */}
```

Usage:

```
import updateState from 'myModule';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    updateMyState = (source, typedText) => this.setState(
        (state, props) => updateState(state, props, source, typedText)
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <JourneyList messages={this.state.journeyMessageList} 
                updateJourneyList={this.updateMyState} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, you suggest me to put all my conditional statement in `updateState`? also, how would I pass my parameters/arguement I need there? Please help me with analogy of my example

Comment: Yes you could pull the constants and your case handling logic into its own module/function if you want to use that across multiple components.

Comment: @OMTheEternity See my updated answer. If you don't need e.g. `props` in your updater function you can also omit that parameter by just not passing it to your updater.

Comment: ok,,, and hence I can Use `handleUserInteraction` into my `render()` method as passing props into other component like `<JourneyList messages={this.state.journeyMessageList} 
                    updateJourneyList={this.handleUserInteraction} />` ??

Comment: @OMTheEternity Yeah you can pass that handler around like any other handler. `handleUserInteraction` is just an arbitrary name in my example. In your example it would be `updateMyState`.

Comment: Got It!!! That will suffice.... Thank You so much.. I would appreciate it, if you can share some doc urls which is in context of this Question

Comment: @OMTheEternity I already linked the documentation for `setState()` which describes how to use it with an updater function in my first sentence. Other then that currently nothing relevant other then that comes into my mind. But feel free to edit my answer if you come across other relevant resources.

Comment: @OMTheEternity Glad to hear it helped!

Comment: I have a quick question..... if you see my question's code.. you can see that I have to `setState` as per different `if` conditions, now since you have suggested me to create a stateless component, how I am supposed to setState in stateless component `updateState` ???

Comment: @OMTheEternity Maybe it did not get clear yet. I did not suggest to use a stateless component. The component that calls `setState()` is still a stateful component. Just that it now uses a plain function to calculate the new state. This function contains your common updating logic. So the `updateState` function in my example is just a normal function, not a component.

Comment: @OMTheEternity But probably you want a generic `Dashboard` component that handles state that is common for all dashboards and let it accept additional props to modify its appearance and data display. Then your `WebDashboard` renders a `Dashboard` that has that logic. It is hard to know just from a small example. I will provide an example later.